# Knockoutjs and phonegap load

Tags: cordova, knockout.js, load

I´m using knockout for translate my phonegap APP, knockout is not working when I use "load" function.

For example:

```
$('#menu').load('./includes/inc-menu.html');
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

The content in inc-menu.html isnt translate and the code without load yes.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not tried below script, but my guess is that you need to apply binding after content is loaded.

```
$('#menu').load('./includes/inc-menu.html', function(){
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(), $(#menu)[0]); // apply bindings only to element with id as menu
});
```